# What is the language of Sigma^n? Confused about meanining

Tags: formal-languages, automata, regular-languages, computation-models

I am learning the Theory of Computation, and I came across the language $\Sigma^n$. Could someone please explain what that could mean if $\Sigma$ is the alphabet?

Thank you so much!

Comment: We identify $\Sigma$ with the set of all words over $\Sigma$ of length $1$. Then $\Sigma^n$ is just the $n$-th power of the language $\Sigma$, a definition you must have seen in class.

Comment: For example, if $\Sigma = \{a,b\}$ then we identify $\Sigma$ with the language consisting of the words $a$ and $b$.

Answer (score 1):

By definition $\Sigma^n$ is simply $\underbrace{\Sigma\times \Sigma \times \cdots \times\Sigma}_{n \ \text{times}} = \{(\sigma_1, \sigma_2, \ldots, \sigma_n): \forall \ i\in [n], \sigma_i \in \Sigma \}$ which is the set of ordered tuples of length $n$ over $\Sigma$. Usually, when we refer to a tuple $w = (\sigma_1, \sigma_2, \ldots, \sigma_n)$, we omit the commas "," and the parenthesis "(" and ")", so the tuple $w$ is written as $\sigma_1\cdot \sigma_2\cdots \sigma_n$ to which we refer as a word of length $n$ over $\Sigma$. In other words, $\Sigma^n$ is the set of all words of length $n$ over $\Sigma$.

Formally, the map that maps a tuple in $\Sigma^n$ to the word that we get by omitting the commas and the parenthesis from the tuples, is a bijection from $\Sigma^n$ to the words of length $n$ over $\Sigma$.

Comment: Thank you for the answers! If $n = 5$, could I have any words of length 2?

Comment: No. $\Sigma^5$ contains all words of length $5$, and only them.